# drop down not closing when click second element

Tags: jquery

When i click first element it's opening dropdown and swapping but when i click second element not closing dropdown. when i click second element it should be close and swap elements. In mobile also closing menu.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 /*$(".item:nth-child(2)").css("dispaly", "none");
        $(".item:nth-child(2)").css("height", window.innerHeight);
  */$(".item:nth-child(1)").click(function(){
    $(".item:nth-child(2)").show();
  });/*
  $(".item:nth-child(2)").click(function(){
    $(".item:nth-child(2)").hide();
  });
 */
 
 
   $(".menu").find('.item').click(function(){
  var index = $(this).index();
  $('select[name=size]')
  .find('option:eq(' + index + ')')
  .attr('selected',true);
  $(this).prependTo('.menu');
 });
 
});
```

```css
body{margin: 0;color: #000;}
 /* CSS Document */
 .menu{width: 500px; background: #000;  margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;color: #fff;font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif"}
 .menu .item{cursor: pointer;}
 .menu .item:nth-child(2){text-align: left;}
 .menu .item:nth-child(2) span{border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
<div class="ind item">IND</div>
<div class="int item" style="display: none;"><span>INT</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, problem is that - because of dynamicall changes/reordering in DOM, indexes aren't updated, so real event target must be choosen (thus, events are delegated to static element - menu). This could be the fix:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".menu").on('click', '.item:first-child', function(){
  
  
    $(".item").eq(1).show();
       
  });
 
 
    $(".menu").on('click','.item:nth-child(2)', function(){
$(this).prependTo('.menu');



        $(this).next().hide();

 });
 
});
```

```css
body{margin: 0;color: #000;}
 /* CSS Document */
 .menu{width: 500px; background: #000;  margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;color: #fff;font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif"}
 .menu .item{cursor: pointer;}
 .menu .item:nth-child(2){text-align: left;}
 .menu .item:nth-child(2) span{border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
<div class="ind item">IND</div>
<div class="int item" style="display: none;"><span>INT</span></div>
</div>
```

Swapping and hide/show now works.